# Obtain the graph of the autocorrelation function in ARIMA models

Tags: time-series, python

I am implementing an ARIMA model in Python for forecasting U.S. GDP.

I am interested in obtaining the graph for the autocorrelation function. I obtained the values for ACF but I can not see the graph even though I have written

```
>>>import statsmodels.api as sm
>>>sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf
```

Enter and nothing appears.
Just this

```
<function plot_acf at 0x0000000014E44358>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: This appears to be off-topic, as it is not about statistics as such, but "only" about the programming aspects. For this, StackOverflow.com is more suitable. However, there you will be expected to ask much more specific questions, "showing your work", and including a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot the parenthesis at the end:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf()
```